# QSerialPort Error: Device Not Open

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a Qt application that I am attempting to build on Linux. I have a FTDI device that I want to interact with using the Qt application I have made, however I keep getting an error message that the device failed to open. I have checked whether the device is connected to the PC and it is connected given that I can retrieve the serial number, device description, etc. from the device. I have also tried this on Windows and it works without a problem, only Linux.

Here's my code by the way:

```
foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {
        if(info.description() != "")
        {
            QSerialPort *serial = new QSerialPort(info);
            serial -> setPortName(info.portName());

            if (!serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
                    std::cout << "Fail to open device" << std::endl;
                }

            serial -> setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
            serial -> setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
            serial -> setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);

        }
    }
```

Comment: [From the QT docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#open): "and sets an error code which can be obtained by calling the [error()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#error-prop) method." Getting that error code would be extremely helpful in determining the cause of the error.

Comment: @user4581301 I get an error code of 2.

Comment: According to the docs I linked above, error 2 is permissions error. Doesn't look like you are allowed to open that device. We're outside where I'm comfortable giving advice here. You may have to hack the udev rules. Try a google search for "set FTDI permissions <your linux distribution here>"

Comment: I think this is permission error.... try running your program as admin. Then if that works add your self to the dialout group

Comment: Agree with @code_fodder here, at least for a short term proof of concept test. Run your program through `sudo` or a console elevated with `su`. Once you have confirmed, find a polite way to run the program without globally elevated privledges.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, admin is just a "quick hack-test run", it'll be the dialout group that you can add yourself to for more permenant solution. I went through this not so long ago : )  ... that's the group that all the comports are assigned to.. have to do the same to run putty, so its not a code issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add yourself to the dialout group:

`sudo usermod -a -G dialout YOURUSERNAME`

or

`sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME dialout`

Then logout and login again to take affect.

Comment: I've executed this command and have added myself, however it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Also try `ls -l /dev/` to show you the groups of the ports, I am sure you will see its dialout... if not then we do the same for the other group.

Comment: Never mind, that did the trick. I forgot to run as an administrator and now it works. However, is there a way to open the device such that the user doesn't need to have root privileges?

Comment: Yes, add yourself to the group :)  ... but you need to logout/login after to take affect. If dialout don't work then print the output of `ls -l /dev` in your question (just print the lines for the comport in question) if its usb then it should be `ttyUSBx` or somthing...

Comment: Oh, okay I see. Thanks for the help and the quick response. :)