# PlatformIO cannot open ftdi device (Arduino with esp32)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, esp32, platformio

I am new to Arduino and using the esp32 and I am using PlatformIO to command my project in C++ through VSCode. I just downloaded my project folder and opened it in PlatformIO and attempted to run the existing code (over 1000 lines) which is meant to command an exoskeleton. When I run the program, however, I get error messages, as follows:

Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010, description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'
Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6014, description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'

I feel like I am missing something very basic, but everything I search for gives me very advanced problems, and I am hoping someone could dumb this down for me.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

By the way, I am actually using Mac, and the output when I enter the ls -ls /dev/tty.usbserial-1410 is:

0 crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   2  7 Dec 14:13 /dev/tty.usbserial-1410

Comment: Want to tell us what version of Linux you're using? It's likely a permissions problem. What does `ls -ls /dev/ttyXXX` (where XXX is the name of the USB port in /dev that you're using) show?

Comment: Other than @romkey comment, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256089/4902099).

Answer (score 2):

You may used a different type of esp32 module (there're lots of variants in the market) from the original design. You have 2 options,

- If the software works and you don't want to modify it, then try to find the same type of esp32 module specified by design.
- Find out vid/pid from your current esp32 module and update software to connect. Refer to below procedure.

The procedures to update usb serial binding,

1. Run `lsusb` to find out vid/pid
   [lsusb commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQwO.jpg)
2. update the existing rule specified with vid 0403 and pid 6010 to your current vid/pid, usually the rule file is under `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.
3. Run `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` to activate.

Comment: lsusb doesn't return anything for me, it says "command not found". I forgot to mention this in the original post, but I'm using a MacBook; is this command different for macs?

Comment: Since you are using Mac, I assume it is for dev/test purpose. A more straightforward way is to find out the serial port name used in the code, and replace it with your actual one, e.g. /dev/tty.usbserial-1410 in your case. In fact, serial binding is to create an alias name for the specific serial port filtered by "vid/pid", so the code could always open the correct port via the alias name, which is mainly used in production deployment.